# Summernote Image Uplaod With Spatie Media Library On Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire, summernote

I'm using Laravel Livewire and Summernote editor. I'm using Spatie Media Library for uploaded images on editor.

On my **edit page** component I've this code:

```
        $dom = new \DomDocument();
        $dom->loadHtml($this->pageBody, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        $pageImages = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

        if ($pageImages) {
            foreach ($pageImages as $k => $img) {
                $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
                $this->page->addMediaFromBase64($data)->toMediaCollection('pageImages');
                $img->removeattribute('src');
                $img->setattribute('src', $this->page->getMedia('pageImages')[$k]->getUrl());
            }
        }
```

The problem is, if I click "update" button all images are uploading again in to new subfolders and generating new database records. How can I prevent uploading duplicate files or check before upload from database?

Comment: You need to identify which images have already been uploaded, and ignore them within an `if` statement. Put an attribute on already stored images perhaps, and check for that?

Comment: Or attach an event to upload images, instead of putting it in the upload method